# Google App Maker - How to bind to a relation on a query datasource?

Tags: database, data-binding, widget, google-app-maker, database-relations

I have a model 'Invoices' which I created another datasource on (Past_due_invoices) with a query script to return all records where invoice_due_date._lessThan = new Date(); It returns all the records as expected.

I have an account details page where I've put in a table that I had imagined I would use 'Accounts: PastDueInvoices(relation)' as the datasource to only return the past due invoices for that account, but I have yet to find a way to bind to that datasource.

To complicate matters, I will also need to filter that data by (@datasource.relations.Payments.items).reduce

I have read all I could find on the subject over the last week.

Is there a better approach, or what am I missing to be able to relate to that datasource?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to work is instead of binding to 'Accounts:PastDueInvoices (Relation)', I bound directly to 'Invoices' and used the following onAttach for the table.

```
var datasource = widget.datasource;
var accountName = widget.parent.datasource.item.account_name;
var totalPayments = datasource.item.Payments.reduce((b,a) => Number (a.payment_amount) + Number(b) , 0);

datasource.query.filters.Accounts.account_name._equals = accountName;
datasource.query.filters.invoice_due_date._lessThan = new Date;
datasource.query.filters.invoice_total._greaterThan = totalPayments;

datasource.load();
```

I'd still lover to hear if there is a better approach.

Thanks